# Set LaTeX version to use when exporting using org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

In my `.emacs`, I have the following:

```
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f"))
```

However, when exporting an `org` it uses the "wrong" version of `latexmk`. More precisely, from my `shell` (outside of `emacs`), I use:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/latexmk
```

But, it seems like, `org` is using a different one that is associated to the wrong version of TeXLive. How can I set the **right** LaTeX to be used when exporting `org` files?

Comment: Emacs use the same `PATH` var as in the shell env from where you launched it. What do you see when you do `which latexmk` in the terminal (from where you launched emacs)?

Comment: From the terminal I see the right `latexmk`. I launch `emacs` from a shortcut, so I don't know what's its `PATH`. How can I check it?

Comment: Examine the value of `exec-path` (for example by pressing `M-:` and then typing `exec-path`) to see what directories are available to Emacs to search for `latexmk`. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that Org will launch a process with `latexmk` rather than executing a shell command with that text.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Emacs on OS X, then it may have different environment variables values than the ones you see in terminal shell. You can check the value of PATH environment variable that Emacs process has by typing `M-x` `getenv` RET `PATH`. Most likely you don't have `/usr/texbin` in `PATH` that `getenv` will show you.  I run emacs from shell prompt on OS X like this

```
$ /usr/local/opt/emacs/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

to get the exact environment I have in shell. This path to Emacs works if you installed Emacs as a homebrew package.  Otherwise the path to emacs executable is likely to be different.  All other solutions don't quite work for me since upgrade to OS X 10.10.

I guess you could put the absolute path to `latexmk` in the definition of `org-latex-to-pdf-process`